# it is possible to speed up PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I've tried to write a fast regular expression, but when I test it, PHP (preg_replace_callback) will have houndres of steps to get the results and I think that's not a good perfomance - that must be faster.

My RegEx-Code: `\{if\s{1}(.+?)\}\n(((?R)|.*?)+)\{\/if\}`

Code, that should be parsed (recursiveley):

```
{if $name == 'Tree'}
    Hey, this is a Tree!
{/if}

{if $name == 'Example'}
    {if $number == '1'}
        Hey, this is an Example with the number 1
    {/if}
{/if}
```

You can test the example on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/bgR75x/1).

Is there a way to speed up my regular expression or do I have to accept that speed?

Comment: `\{if\s(.+?)}\R((?>(?!\{\/?if[}\s]).|(?R))*?)\{\/if}` ?

Comment: Yes, like that! it's a bit faster than my regex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)\{if\s(.+?)}\R((?>(?!\{\/?if[}\s]).|(?R))*?)\{\/if}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bgR75x/2)

**Details**

- `\{if\s` - `{if` and a whitespace
- `(.+?)` - Group 1: any one or more chars, as few as possible
- `}` - a `}` char
- `\R` - any line break sequence
- `((?>(?!\{\/?if[}\s]).|(?R))*?)` - Group 2: any char other than a char starting a `{/if` or `{if`+whitespace char sequence, or the whole pattern recursed, 0 or more times, but as few as possible
- `\{\/if}` - `{/if}` text